# oneliner subset of an R dataframe for use in a table

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to make a series of histograms from columns in a dataframe where I look at the frequency of column A (a text descriptor.) depending upon the value of column B (a number). I would like to change the cutoff of value B and make a series of histograms to see what the distributions look like.

right now I am using:

```
x <- data[data$B> 10,]
y <- table(x$A)
hist(y)
```

and I could run this for a number of values of B. However,I would like to have a one liner like this:

```
hist(table(data$A where data$B > 10))
```

but I can't get the syntax right. Anyone have an suggestions?

Comment: this will do it:hist(table(data[data$B > 10,]$A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subset `data$a` instead of `data`:

```
hist(table(data$a[data$b > 10]))
```

Comment: i get " incorrect number of dimensions" when I do that. But I can put the $Column name after the subset.

Comment: You above code is inconsistent so maybe you had a typo? You can also use `data[data$B > 10, "A"]` or other forms ...

Comment: you are right. I was typing this: hist(table(data$a[data$b >10,]))    the comma was killing me!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(data,B>10),aes(A)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: thanks.  this works but ggplot took a lot longer - i imagine because it took a very fine bin so it plotted a lot more lines.

Comment: You can adjust the binwidth like so: geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1). You can easily use one of the plyr functions to split the data and create individual histograms automatically (in 2-3 lines of code).

Comment: thank you @maiasaura but the ggplot solution is making my computer churn where the simple plot is instantaneous.